# Website in production, attempts session ssh, http

Tags: linux, security, http, ssh, webserver

I want to learn management web server, for this, I have a web server in production (open to the world, T_T), I have some applications mounted in this (very small, only for test).

When I check my logs (`ssh`, `http`), I have a lot of attempts in `ssh` session and I have a lot of attempts of route in `http`, for example:

http:

```
/admin
/managemend
/security
```

ssh:

```
Failed log user one with password 1234
Failed log user two with password password
```

My questions are:

1. I would like to know what normal is this.
2. How I can prevent this?
3. What should monitor addition logs http and ssh.

I would greatly appreciate if you could give me the name of some tools for server management and recommended books addition some recommendations. (Open source please XD.)

Thank you very very much.

Comment: This is normal, a lot of robot will attempt this if you allow password authentication. If you want to prevent this disable password authentication otherwise install fail2ban to prevent brute force attack

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I'll give a look to program, even so I do not keep quiet,  especially attempts to http, I would like to know a little more.